# how to run DTs packaging in mssql server automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql

Hai...

I have created a Dts package from my local server to a remote server and saved the dts package by scheduling every 10 hours but it is not updating the data if i am trying to run it manually it is showing error..

How can i solve this problem please help me its imp for me

Comment: please give us a version & show us the error

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer this without knowing what versions of SQL Server you're using, which would also tell us if it's DTS or SSIS.  It would also be very helpful if you list the error(s) that you are getting.

Since you mention DTS, I'm going to assume here that you're using SQL Server 2000.  In my experience, it's usually a permissions issue when you receive errors even when manually running packages.  Make sure you're using a login in your connection to the remote server that has all the required privileges on the remote server to do what you need to do.